# Version conflict in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azureservicebus

I'am getting this error when trying to use Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent in my project.

> Severity  Code    Project Description File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error NU1607  ProjectX.Auth.Web   Version conflict detected for
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory. Reference the package
>   directly from the project to resolve this issue.
>
> ProjectX.Auth.Web (>= 1.0.0) -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.All (>= 2.0.0) ->
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault (>= 2.0.0) ->
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory (>= 3.14.1)
>
> ProjectX.Auth.Web (>= 1.0.0) -> ProjectX.Auth.Infrastructure (>=
>   1.0.0) -> ProjectX.Shared.Infrastructure (>= 1.0.0) -> ProjectX.Shared.ServiceBus (>= 1.0.0) ->
>   Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent (>= 1.2.0) ->
>   Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent (>= 1.2.0) ->
>   Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure.Authentication (>= 2.3.1) ->
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory (>= 3.13.9).

Any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: Have you tried to `Reference the package directly from the project to resolve this issue`?

Comment: @KirkLarkin -> I tried to add Nuget packages to the projects: ProjectX.Auth.Web = Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory (>= 3.14.1)  and ProjectX.Shared.ServiceBus -> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory (>= 3.13.9). If thats what you mean?

Comment: @RuneJensen try `install-package Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` for all `ProjectX.` projects in the dependency chain - that would include `ProjectX.Auth.Infrastructure` and `ProjectX.Shared.Infrastructure`

Comment: @KirkLarkin -> It seams to work adding the packages to the entire dependency chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the method proposed in the question comments by @KirkLarkin and added the NuGet packages in the entire dependency chain.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a [binding redirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions) to redirect to the latest version of Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory (3.14.1).

Alternatively, you can also [auto-generate binding redirects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/how-to-enable-and-disable-automatic-binding-redirection).

```
 <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>

 <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
```

Comment: I tried to add your auto-generate suggestion to all the .csproj files in the dependency chain. But i'am getting the same error.